# Dropbox Sync API or Core API for pure Java

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to if we could use the android sdk, which dropbox provides for Sync API, in a pure java project? if yes, how? what are the changes I need to make to an existing Android project using sync API in order to convert it to java project which would be used in a web app. If this is not possible kindly let me know if it is possible with Core API. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Nitish, I am also looking for similar java library for sync. Did you find/develop any such library? Please share how you solved this problem,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you could make the Android Sync API work, but the Core API does have a Java SDK:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdk
- https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-java-sdk-1.5.3-docs/index.html